# How to display int with printf in C

Tags: c, printf

I am having some weird trouble when I am trying to display an int in C with the printf() function. This is the code I am using

```
            printf("To compute pi enter n: ");
            int n_term = 1;

            printf("n: %d \n", &n_term); 
            scanf("%d", &n_term);
            printf("n: %d", &n_term);
```

I realized there was an issue because when I try to simply print n_term back to the user, even before they input any value for n_term, it comes out with this giant number, 2686776. Any insight as to what the issue here would be greatly appreciated. I am using gcc compiler if that makes any difference.

Comment: `printf("n: %d \n", n_term);` Drop the ampersand

Comment: Why are you passing the address? `printf("n: %d \n", n_term); ` is sufficient. Are you actually confused by asymmetrical usage in `scanf()`?

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the ampersand (&) on the printf call. You are printing the address of the variable n_term donwcasted as an integer.

Comment: For future reference, int* is being implicitly casted to int.

Comment: @JoachimOlsson actually, nothing gets casted to anything; the code has no casts nor implicit conversions; in return, it has undefined behavior. printf might try to reinterpret (part of) the bitwise representation of the pointer as an `int`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant You're right, I misunderstood the signature of printf. Apologies. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("n: %d \n", &n_term); 
                   ^ ampersand sign is not required, it points to address.
printf("n: %d", &n_term);
                ^ ampersand sign is not required, it points to address.
```

Comment: It's not just not required, it's plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is required to read address of variable ( like in `scanf()` ).
So, it is not required in `printf()`.
your code should be like this:

```
            printf("n: %d \n", n_term); 
            scanf("%d", &n_term);
            printf("n: %d", n_term);
```