# "Triple" Function doesn't return value

Tags: c, printf

I'm new to C programming, and I'm trying to learn by myself and by searching on the internet. I've recently heard about functions and tried to make a function to triple à number, but then, this code wouldn't return anything, even after trying everything I could.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int triple(int number)
{
    return 3 * number;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numberToTriple = 3;
    int result = triple(numberToTriple);
    printf(result);
    return 0;
}
```

If someone can help me understand what is wrong and how to fix it, it would be very helpful. But I'm not getting discouraged.

Comment: You'll want to look for examples of the `printf` function - you're definitely not calling it correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're so close. `printf("%d\n", result);`.

Comment: [how to display int with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801328/how-to-display-int-with-printf-in-c)

Comment: Any decent compiler should have given you a warning when trying to build that code. Please listen to the compiler.

Comment: Since this is the place for good unsolicited advice, you should only include what you intend to use, in this example you only need to include `stdio.h`

Comment: pay attention to the error messages given by the compiler

Answer (score 2):

All thing in your code is right except `printf` function.
For print a `int` type value,you should write like this:

```
printf("%d",value);
```

Here the code for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int triple(int number)
{
    return 3 * number;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numberToTriple = 3;
    int result = triple(numberToTriple);
    printf("%d\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh right, thanks for this. Really sorry ruining your time, but at least it works now !

Comment: @Tom There is no more output to show.So i dont use the newline.Thanks for your advice.I will  edit my code

Comment: Even if it's the final output, it will end up on the same line as the following command prompt, at least on a Unix system, which is never good.  The only time not to end with a newline is if you have more you wish to add to the line, in which case the newline will come later.